# Comparing rows value of same field in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have a field in attribute table names "Route", with  rows

I want to comapre row one of Field"Route" with row two of the same field if the value bigger or smaller then insert a value in another field :

WHEN rownumber 1  of " Route" = rownumber 2 of "Route" then insert 1 n " class"

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *Virtual Layer* is an option here, below syntax will get you a "class" field populated with 1, 2, 3, and -.

- If the row value is equal to the one above: `1`
- If the row value is greater than the one above: `2`
- If the row value is less than the one above: `3`
- The first row will be given `-`, as it has no corresponding value above.

---

Workflow:

1. From menu go to `Layer | Add Layer | Add/Edit Virtual Layer`
2. In the next window, Click <kbd>Import</kbd> button to load your layer in.
3. Copy and paste the below code into the Query window. Click on <kbd>OK</kbd>
4. A new layer `virtual layer` will be added to the Layers Panel.
5. Open the attribute table and check if you see `Class` field.
6. If all ok, please save this virtual layer as a new file (it disappears when QGIS is closed).

---

```
SELECT t1.*, 
         CASE WHEN Route =
                    (SELECT Route
                        FROM network t2
                     WHERE t2.rownum = t1.rownum - 1) THEN '1'
              WHEN Route >
                    (SELECT Route
                        FROM network t2
                     WHERE t2.rownum = t1.rownum - 1) THEN '2'
              WHEN Route <
                     (SELECT Route
                        FROM network t2
                     WHERE t2.rownum = t1.rownum - 1) THEN '3'
         ELSE '-' END AS Class
FROM network t1
```

---

[Edit]

- Your layer name `network`
- Field to be referred: `Route`
- New field to be created: `Class`

Both `t1` and `t2` are aliases for your `network` layer in this syntax, and we do not need to change them.

Comment: @ Kazuhito :at first thank you very much for your response, but will you explain more what do you write here , and what do you mean with t1 and T2 ..?

Comment: My_Layer name is "network" , and field name " Route" that i want compare it rows , and the field name "Class" that i want insert result in it. if  i work with you suggestion my code dont work:                                          SELECT t1.*, 
         CASE WHEN Route =
          (SELECT Route
             FROM network t2
             WHERE t2.rownum = t1.rownum - 1) THEN '1'
             WHEN Route >
                 (SELECT Route
                FROM network t2
              WHERE t2.rownum = t1.rwonum - 1) THEN '2'
       ELSE '-' END AS classFROM network t1

Comment: @AEDEDA Thanks for your response. Let me add some more detail in the process and modify the syntax to accommodate your layer name.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, but i get this error                                "Query Preparation Error on PRAGMA table_info(_tview): no such column:t2.fid"

Comment: @AEDEDA I changed the  field name from `fid` to `rownum`, which is probably you have now. Will you give it a try?